# jQuery addClass not working in Bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a *Bootstrap* table somewhat like this:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <th data-field="name" data-formatter="nameFormatter"></th>
        <th data-field="number" data-formatter="numberFormatter"></th>
        <th class="newClass"></th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#myTable').on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element) {
    // $('.newClass').removeClass('newClass');
    $('.newClass').addClass('shown') // <-- this doesn't seem to work
}
```

**CSS**

```
td.newClass {
    background-image: url("../../Content/Images/open.png");
}

tr.shown td.newClass {
    background-image: url("../../Content/Images/close.png");
}
```

I am trying to `addClass()` on the row click event of the table but it doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something or doing something incorrectly.

Comment: This looks suspect: " $('#myTable').on('click-row.bs.table' ".  Is that an actual event?  If you do a console.log or alert inside that event handler does it fire?

Comment: how come `removeClass` works then??

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla, nothing happens with `click` being added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your CSS does not match your markup:

```
tr.shown td.newClass
{
    background-image: url("../../Content/Images/close.png");

}
```

Which is looking for the `shown` class on the table-row. But it looks like you are adding the `shown` class to the table-cell:

```
$('#myTable').on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element) {
    //$('.newClass').removeClass('newClass');
    $('.newClass').addClass('shown')    // isn't $('.newClass') the cell and not the row?
}
```

**UPDATE:**

To fix this you can change your CSS:

```
td.newClass.shown { ... }
```

or your jQuery:

```
$element.addClass('shown');
```

Comment: i think i am doing something really stupid here....your code worked but it changed the image for the entire column and i only want it for that row.

Comment: You might try: `$element.addClass('shown');` instead. This assumes that the table-row is passed as the `$element` argument.

Answer (score 1):

It will help you :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  
  
  $("#myTable tr").on('click',function(){
    
    $(this).find(".newClass").addClass("shown");
    
  });
  
 
  
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>SPLessons</title>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.1.4" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>

  <body >
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h3>
          <a href="http://www.splessons.com"> SPLessons.com </a>
        </h3>
        
        
        <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered">
          <tr>
              <th data-field="name" data-formatter="nameFormatter"></th>
              <th data-field="number" data-formatter="numberFormatter"></th>
              <th class="newClass"></th>
          </tr>
      </table>
        
        
        
      </div>
    </div>
   
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```